# Using Tipsy with Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, jquery-plugins, tipsy

I would like to know how to make use of plugins within my Rails app. For example, while Tipsy (http://onehackoranother.com/projects/jquery/tipsy/) does come in gem form it would be great if someone could show me how to integrate it without the gem as I can then apply this to other plugins that aren't in gem form.

A few questions:
1) Should I use the vendor folder?
2) Should I reference the js and css before the application in my application layout file?
3) Where does the image go and how do I reference the image from the Tipsy css file?

p.s. I'm using Rails 4 by the way!

Answer (score 0):

Final answer: Yes, rails 4 deprecates css/javascript plugins. You can either add them to the typical assets folder, or extract them into a gem.

[Rails 4: Where to put JavaScript/CSS plugins](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16685152/rails-4-where-to-put-javascript-css-plugins)