# Where to put js/css/images plugins in Rails 4?

Tags: javascript, css, ruby-on-rails, image, plugins

There is a similar question: [Rails 4: Where to put JavaScript/CSS plugins](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16685152/rails-4-where-to-put-javascript-css-plugins). But none of the answers actually answer my question.
This plugin is third-party, so I'd like to put it somewhere in **vendor** directory (and not in the **assets** directory).
Also I think it's better to keep all the plugin files in one directory, so I don't want to spread js, css files and images into different directories.

So is there any nice way of dealing with vendor js plugins in Rails 4?

Answer (score 0):

Add the third party plugin as:-

Approach 1:-

Consider the example, to add gem 'bootstrap-sass', do like that:-

In Gemfile:-

```
gem 'bootstrap-sass', '3.3.1', :path => 'vendor/bootstrap-sass-3.3.1'
```

Puts the whole plugin of bootstrap in `vendor/` folder so the directory structure will looks like

```
vendor/bootstrap-sass-3.3.1/assets/
vendor/bootstrap-sass-3.3.1/lib/
vendor/bootstrap-sass-3.3.1/tasks/
vendor/bootstrap-sass-3.3.1/ #other directory and files
```

Approach 2:-

If only third party js files are included, then put js files in `vendor/assets/javascripts/` and require it in application.js as :-

```
//= require file_name_without_js_extension
```

Example:-

```
//= require jwplayer
```

For css, put css files in `vendor/assets/stylesheets/` and require it in application.css as :-

```
*= require file_name_without_css_extension
```

Comment: Thank you! But what if I want to use a plugin that isn't packed as a gem? Should I just put js and css under corresponding vendor directory? Will it be automatically included?

Comment: so it's not possible to put the plugin in one directory?

Comment: @Stephan, i am in a similar situation as you are. I have tons of thirdy party plugins and do not want to spread them across stylesheet and javascript directory in the vendor folder. Have you fond a solution yet?